# System Upgrade: Scheduling and steps

Tags: modal-dialog, workflow, updating

I'm working on a system that offers 2 options to upgrade:

1. "Remind me Later"
2. "Install"
3. If you click on "Remind me Later" you can enter the number of days in which you will be reminded to upgrade.
4. If you click on "Install", you can enter a certain hour of the day in which the update will take place -or- you can hit install now.

I find this very clunky and am not sure how to design it. Should each button trigger a pop up? Not sure if anyone knows of any examples I can take a look at.

Comment: What's the context?  Is this a web app, desktop dialog, etc?

Answer (score 4):

I like the way it was done in Mac OS X with just two options available: "Install" and "Not now".

Choosing the "Not now" option will postpone update for some time (users were able to configure the delay in System Settings, AFAIR), pressing "Install" will install immediately.

So, your solution is almost the same, except two last items, which, I think, is unnecessary.

1. The idea behind a postpone is to not distract user from urgent tasks, but introducing additional options will lead to the opposite effect, especially when it's about figuring out something (number of days to delay update for, in your case). So I suggest to make three options instead: "Install now", "Remind tomorrow" and "Remind in a week" (you may test best values for delays, of course). The nice thing is that user will be able to choose between two periods quickly (one short period, but NOT too short, and another - long enough to go deeper in her tasks without any distraction).
2. Although, scheduling update for the certain time is OK, I think it may be confusing. It seems like it's not a simple process, but instead a process which will take time, may require restarting of the app or even the system, so it's better to just let people choose the time reminder will pop up next time. I think it's easy to figure out and much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Could you divide the options into 3?

- "Install Now"
- "Install Later"
- "Remind Me Later"

That might be more clear to the user before they take an action that they actually have 3 options rather than two.

Comment: I picked Install Later because right now I'm doing something important.  What promise do I have that I won't be doing something important later? Per alexey's answer, I'd omit "Install Later."